# Geom_smooth error disappears when it exceeds y-limit in ggplot, how prevent this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently plotting a lot of data using the geom_smooth method in ggplot, using this code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(time, od, colour = media,fill=media)) +
  geom_smooth(method="loess",span=0.3) +
  scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.01,1))
```

This produces the plot that looks like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, the error fill from the geom_smooth plot disappears when the values get close to the limits of the y-axis. This can be solved by increasing the y-axis interval, however I would prefer to keep the interval from 0 and up.

Is there any way to plot this in the same interval as in the image, and not miss any of the geom_smooth fill?

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: Instead of setting the limits via the scale try with `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.01,1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved using:

```
+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0.01,1))
+ scale_y_log10()
```

Instead of

```
scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.01,1))
```

Thanks to Stefan :)